# How to pass data to ejs file in sails & node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I want to export the data from the database to the ejs file. but every time I get a reference error. I tried all the methods, but I could not solve my problem. my codes are as follows:

**Controller:**

```js
 module.exports = {
  page: function(req, res)
  {
    Users.findOne({'id':1}, function(users){
      res.view('page',{page: users});
    });
  }
};
```

**EJS File:**

```js
<%=page.user_name%>
```

But when load a localhost:1337/users/page get this error:

```
ReferenceError: sailsproject\views\listele.ejs:1 >> 1| <%=page.user_name%> 2| page is not defined at eval
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use forEach for read an object..

in your ejs file:

```
<% page.forEach(function(data) { %>
 <%= data.user_name %>
<% }) %>
```